# How to prevent multiple event listeners on Liferay SPA SennaJS?

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-7, senna.js

I want to fire a function every time I change a page in Liferay.

```
Liferay.on('endNavigate', function(event) {
    functionToExecuteOnEveryPage();
});
```

It works, but every time I change the page the event `'endNavigate'` is invoked multiple times.

[image]
The first time I change the page the function is executed once, and the second time I change the page the function is executed two times, and the third time I change the page the function is executed three times, and so on..

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Maybe it's better your functionToExecuteOnEveryPage() is ready for this scenario..

Comment: you can use `beforeNavigate`  method as well.which type of logic you want to perform?

Comment: @pratikpatel `beforeNavigate` fires before navigation starts. I want to execute my function after the page is fully loaded that's why I use `endNavigate`.

Comment: Your problem is already defined in Liferay documentation. You can detach the event listener. This [link](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/automatic-single-page-applications#detaching-global-listeners) may help you.

Comment: @pratikpatel Can you post your answer with an example?